# What password manager do you use for ssh?

Tags: ssh, passwords

Or what resolution do you use to access more than 10 ssh connections?

Comment: I made a small SSH Connector in Expect script. However, this is not password management since the Passwords are stored in Plain Text! -> https://github.com/NLDev/SSH-Starter

Answer (score -3):

Don't use plain passwords, generate public ssh keys and upload them to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote machine. It's much safer and quicker.

Comment: This is not an answer to his question. Please keep your comments in the comment section.

Comment: "Or what resolution do you use to access more than 10 ssh connections?" I'm sure that my answer is correct.